# Google Chrome do not allow to add https://raw.github.com/kbwood/svg/master/jquery.svgdom.js resource

Tags: google-chrome

I added`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/kbwood/svg/master/jquery.svgdom.js" style="cursor: auto;"></script>` to the page and open in **Google- Chrome** but it shows following message in console.
**Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/kbwood/svg/master/jquery.svgdom.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.** But the code do not show any kind of error or warning in the console in **FireFox**

Comment: Github is not meant to be a CDN.

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong. Stop hotlinking and host the file yourself.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6106757